# The choice of scalar factors in the proof of the Schwarz inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, normed-spaces, inner-products

In this proof for the Schwarz Inequality, they seemingly arbitrarily choose $r = w\cdot w$ and $s =-(v\cdot w)$. Why did they make these selections? I don't understand where these values for $r$ and $s$ come from. Please guide.

[image]

Comment: $(12)$ holds for any $r$ and $s$. In particular, it works for the values that prove the result. This is the "rabbit out of the hat" technique.

Comment: okay. thank you. then they probably found them via trial and error? Also why did my question get down voted?--I want to know to avoid future down votes. Thank you.

Comment: @user2877144 regarding the downvotes - there is a plague of questions here of the style, "HERE'S MY PROBLEM!!~**~  SOLVE IT. K. Thanks!~~**~". Usually these questions show no indication of any work of their own. I'm not saying your question is one of these, but there is some superficial resemblance that may have rubbed people the wrong way. [Here's some tips for writing good questions.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This proof is unnecessarily complicated. It's easier to start with

$$
\|\mathbf v+s\mathbf w\|^2\ge0\;,
$$

which yields

$$
\mathbf v\cdot\mathbf v+2s\mathbf v\cdot\mathbf w+s^2\mathbf w\cdot\mathbf w\ge0\;,
$$

and then differentiate with respect to $s$ to find the "worst case" of $s$, yielding

$$
2\mathbf v\cdot\mathbf w+2s\mathbf w\cdot\mathbf w=0\;.
$$

Since the claim is trivially true for $\mathbf w=\mathbf 0$, we can solve for $s$,

$$
s=-\frac{\mathbf v\cdot\mathbf w}{\mathbf w\cdot\mathbf w}\;,
$$

and subtitute above, which, after multiplying through by $\mathbf w\cdot\mathbf w$ and simplifying, yields the claim.

You can do something similar in the two-variable case – differentiating with respect to $s$ yields

$$
2r\mathbf v\cdot\mathbf w+2s\mathbf w\cdot\mathbf w=0\;,
$$

and then the choice $r=\mathbf w\cdot\mathbf w$ and $s=-\mathbf v\cdot\mathbf w$ seems less magical.